# I need to understand the Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity

Two observers A and B, in different initial system describe the same physical event with their particular, different space time coordinates . Let the coordinate of the event be $x^\mu$ for observer A and ${x^\prime}^\mu$ for observer B .Both coordinates are connected by means of the Lorentz transformation.
$${x^\prime}^\mu = \sum_{\mu=0}^{3}a^{\nu}_{\mu}x^\mu\equiv a^{\nu}_{\mu}x^\mu\ = (\hat{a}\overset{\Rightarrow}{x})$$
Where $\hat{a}$ denotes the abbreviated version of the transformation matrix and $\overset{\Rightarrow}{x}$ is a 4 dimensional world vector .

I need to understand the Lorentz transformation equation that how it transformed .

EDITED :
How both coordinates are connected in that transformation .

Comment: So, which part are you trying to understand? Describe it more explicit in your questions.

Comment: Forhad_jnu, hwlau is right, it's not at all clear what you want to know. Once you edit the question to make it clear what you're asking, I'll be happy to reopen this. Here's a hint: it can sometimes help you formulate a clearer question if you try to phrase your question as a question.

Comment: The equation already specified explicitly how to relate the x' and x using the summation. What is the problem then?

Comment: Why did we use 4 dimensional world vector ?

Comment: So you want to find out matrix elements of $a$? I think you already know that as it is very standard Lorentz transformation described in the wiki.

Comment: @Forhad_jnu: we usually choose our axes so the $x$ axis lines up with the direction of motion. In that case the $y$ and $z$ coordinates are unchanged by the Lorentz transformation and the problem becomes two dimensional $(t, x)$ to $(t', x')$. However in the general case the axes are not aligned with the direction of motion and all four components of the position will change.

Comment: $\hat{a}$ denotes the abbreviated version of the transformation matrix but how it looks like ? can anyone show me the matrix form please.